# Is overriding certain methods of an instance inside a composite object a good design?

Tags: ios

I am developing an App for iOS .

The class design is below:

My intention is to let the developer who uses the CustomView to set the style for all the labels, but not the text. The text for the labels will be set based on the values set to , entity1, entity2, entity3.

Since I have exposed label1,..label3 through accessors as properties, I am planning to intercept any messages sent to set the text of any of the labels and override it to do nothing. Is this a right design?

```
@interface CustomView:UIVIew{

}

@property (nonatomic) UILabel *label1;
@property (nonatomic) UILabel *label2;
@property (nonatomic) UILabel *label3;

@property (nonatomic) CustomEntity *entity1;
@property (nonatomic) CustomEntity *entity2;
@property (nonatomic) CustomEntity *entity3;

@end

@interface CustomEntity:NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *dsiplayName;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger *totalItems;
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is barely a good design, this is rather hacking. If you require that the text of the labels aren't set, then don't expose the labels as properties.